# how to pass the the object values to the select tag with onChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react code which grabs a part of the text which is an input by user and creates JSON object as an option to select tag. here textContent comes from fileReader with user input and handleChange is related to table. I get this error:

> TypeError: _this6.state.textContent.match is not a function

when I console.log `JSON.stringify(this.state.textContent.match(/[A-Z]+:[0-9]{1,3}/gm))` I get this object `["A:100","B:300","C:400","D:900","E:800"]` which is right but I can't pass this as an option. can anyone help?

```
class AllForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textContent: ""
    };
  }

  handleChanges = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        name={"BIN"}
        placeholder={"choose the value"}
        options={JSON.stringify(
          this.state.textContent.match(/[A-Z]+:[0-9]{1,3}/gm)
        )}
        controlFunc={this.handleChanges(idx)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Select component is:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Select = props => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <select
      name={props.name}
      value={props.selectedOption}
      onChange={props.controlFunc}
      className="form-select"
    >
      <option value="">{props.placeholder}</option>
      {props.options.map(opt => {
        return (
          <option key={opt} value={opt}>
            {opt}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  </div>
);

Select.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  selectedOption: PropTypes.string,
  controlFunc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

export default Select;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is all you want (lacking knowledge of regex) but here is the working code. The only problem is the `JSON.stringify` here. You are getting an array from your `.match`, why do you use `JSON.stringify`?

```js
class AllForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textContent: "A:100B:300C:400D:900E:800",
    };
  }

  handleChanges = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        name={"BIN"}
        placeholder={"choose the value"}
        options={
          this.state.textContent.match(/[A-Z]+:[0-9]{1,3}/gm)
        }
        //controlFunc={this.handleChanges(idx)}
      />
    );
  }
}

const Select = props => (
  <div className="form-group">
    <select
      name={props.name}
      value={props.selectedOption}
      onChange={props.controlFunc}
      className="form-select"
    >
      <option value="">{props.placeholder}</option>
      {props.options && props.options.map(opt => {
        return (
          <option key={opt} value={opt}>
            {opt}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<AllForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I think I did not explain it well. Object values come from User input, so it is not predefined. Select options supposed to change depending on user input. But you are right for the JSON stringfy, I could remove it. Still same error though.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your question well. You mentioned that in the first sentence but since there is no input in your code I couldn't figure it out. Can you provide where and how you get that input from? What kind of text user enters etc?

Comment: user chooses and imports a text file, then regex takes the part of this text file that is our object. I think I need to set a value and update the state with onchange event to pass it.

Comment: I don't know how you import this file and get the values then update the state but `match is not a function` means your `textContent` is not a string when you try `.match`.

Comment: it is a long code so I did not put it here all. And I already import and get the file right, just could not figure out the rest. :)

Comment: Let me understand this again. You want to set a "text" coming from your file and set to it to the `textContent` state? Do you run regex twice, one for file one in your component? How does this text is passed to your component?

Comment: here is the code: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/54mkpqr4kk), you can just create a text copying this "A:100 B:300 C:400 D:900 E:800", so when you choose this text file, you'll see the created object there. So I wanna use those in select tag value or options.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this right :) We choose a file, it has a text, after all we want those text separated into our select options right? If so: https://codesandbox.io/s/o73y67vmq9 If this is not your goal or you can already do this please forgive me.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. "{props.options && .."  this was the trick I guess in Select component. If I remove this I keep getting the error. Text has more information in real case. :)

Comment: Ah, yes before uploading the file, since there is not any `options` as a prop, `.map` fails. This is why I added a condition there. You are welcome. I've updated my answer and added this condition as well. If my answer helped you please consider accepting it.